# Add https binding for existing OWA farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, farm-setup, sharepoint-farm

The site is externally accessible by a https url i.e. `https://intranetsite` and the  OWA is configured for `http://intranet`

How  do I add OWA https bindings for `https://intranetsite`?

And can I use the same certificate i.e. the for OWA?

Existing  Config Farm

```
2 Front end servers Server A  and Server B
2 Distributed Cache Servers C and Server D
2 App Servers Server E and Server F
2 OWA servers Server G and Server H
```